# PHP file containing checkboxes in a table that fetches data from a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want a checkbox for each query that way when the table is populated with data from the db, there is also a checkbox to confirm that booking for each query result.

[image: picture of what I wish to do]

I also want to know how to create a script that once a single checkbox has been selected,I click on submit and it takes me to another page that displays values (route_no,to_city,from_city and price) based on the checkbox selected and route_no corresponding to that checkbox selected. route_no is auto_incrementing and is a primary key(values of route_no range from 0-49).

this is my html form

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","display.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="to_city" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
  <option value="Brisbane">Brisbane</option>
  <option value="Adelaide">Adelaide</option>
  <option value="Newcastle">Newcastle</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

and below is my php file, which has text that shows what I want to acheive. The text has been commented out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"flights");
$sql="SELECT * FROM flights WHERE to_city = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Route_no</th>
<th>to_city</th>
<th>from_city</th>
<th>price</th>
<th>Confirm</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['route_no'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['to_city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['from_city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
/// I want a checkbox here for each query that way when the table is populated with data from the db, there is also a checkbox to confirm that booking for each query result.
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll edit the body section of your php code. Try and see

```
<body>

<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"flights");
$sql="SELECT * FROM flights WHERE to_city = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Route_no</th>
<th>to_city</th>
<th>from_city</th>
<th>price</th>
<th>Confirm</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['route_no'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['to_city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['from_city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"example\" class=\"radio\" value=\"example\"></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
```

here is the jQuery part:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
    var group = ":checkbox[name='"+ $(this).attr("name") + "']";
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $(group).not($(this)).attr("checked",false);
    }
});
```

Comment: it displays:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'checkbox' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp64\www\display.php on line 29

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp64\www\display.php on line 30

Comment: I should keep in mind that my flights table only contains four columns(route_no,to_city,from_city, and price). I dont know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sweet, one more thing does anyone know how to create php code so that only one checkbox can be selected? I also want to know how to create a script that once a single checkbox has been selected,I click on submit and it takes me to another page that displays values (route_no,to_city,from_city and price) based on the checkbox selected? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Novice_29 : did the answer worked? could you please select as correct answer if so.. And about the php code you asked about give me a little time I'll look into it.

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you. Please help me with the other piece of code if you can.

Comment: Hey @Novice_29 , I found an answer for your other problem. You should give the same name for all the textboxes and there is a simple jquery function. I will edit my answer again and I'll add the function at the end. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Well you've already got annotations at the right spot:

```
echo "<form>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['route_no'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['to_city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['from_city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_id' value='" . $variable_that_has_id . "'> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</form>";
```

of course you'll have to replace the `$variable_that_has_id` with whatever `$row[]` correlates with the id in your database.

After that you can create a submit button, then use the form to post data to the same page(or a different one) and you can use the `$_POST` variable to grab whatever values were checked and submitted with the form.

I highly suggest getting familiar with creating forms in html and usage of $_POST since it is relevant to what you're doing.

if you want to allow the user to only select one option change the input type to `"radio"`